# How do I get my wallpaper to stop moving?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, wallpaper

I just changed my background on my home screen on my Galaxy S4 and every time I scroll to a different page the picture moves. How do I get this to stop?

Comment: According to Nicole, 3rd-party launcher `Apex Launcher` is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apex launcher, I remember that you can disable scrolling wallpaper in Apex settings, just try to find this option yourself. FYI: Touchwiz launcher doesn't have scrolling wallpaper from Jelly Bean up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apex Launcher the follow the below settings,

`Open Apex Launcher > Home screen settings > Wallpaper Mode > Single Screen(non-scrolling)`

[image: Screenshot-ApexWallpaperMode]

<sub>Apex Wallpaper Mode Screenshot (Click to enlarge)</sub>

The above settings will not scroll if you have/swipe multiple home screen enabled and the wallpaper will be fixed into one screen and not zoomed and hence will be displayed in single screen as the name says.

Answer (score 0):

No app needed. Just choose multi picture as wallpaper and add only 1 photo. Crop and enjoy your non moving wallpaper.

KitKat 4.4.2, LG G3. Stock.

Answer (score -1):

I use wallpaper [Wallpaper Wizardrii™](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twistedapps.wallpaperwizardrii) from *Google Play Store* which exactly matches your requirement. You can find details in [the app's wiki](http://www.twistedapps.org/?page_id=175).

Comment: How does it do that? Can you provide any link? I couldn't find any app named "wallpaper wizardii" on Play – but more than 100 apps turning up on a search for "wallpaper wizard". So as it currently stands, without the link this cannot be considered a (useful) answer, sorry.

Comment: Sorry  for the wrong app name i have updated my post with playstore link

Comment: Thanks! I've just improved the formatting a little. Still, the answer falls into the category "link only". Could you add some more details on the app – maybe an abstract of the features, especially those addressing the OPs issue? Thanks in advance!