# Prevent wallpaper to slide when sliding the home screen

Tags: home-screen, wallpaper

My question is that when I slide my home screen, my background wallpaper also slides. Not giving me a complete view of full wallpaper on a particular screen.

How to fix it?

Comment: you need to include bit more info such as 1. Device OS, 2. Which home screen Launcher you are using etc.

Comment: if you are using apex you can set the sliding wallpaper off..which has constant background wallpaper and only the home screen slides..

Answer (score 1):

That's the way every android homescreen work. Wallpaper scrolls along with the screen. Stock homescreen doesn't allow us to customize this. You need to get a replacement for homescreen. Like [Apex launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher), [Smart launcher 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerfree), [Solo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=home.solo.launcher.free) or [Nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) etc. They allow you to disable wallpaper scrolling. (or) There's an app called [Wallpaper Wizardrii](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twistedapps.wallpaperwizardrii&hl=en) in Play Store to set the wallpaper in the way you want. Give it a shot.

Comment: Sure when I get to my PC...

Comment: Would like to add to the answer that some phones has multi-wallpaper options as in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/85906/27149) ..and selecting only image disables the scrolling..in that case no 3rd party apps needed..